# Put youtube playlist on website

Tags: html, youtube

How to put youtube video and playlist on a website; I want to show to video list as well not just the videoplayer?

YT embed code shows only the player.

Answer (score 0):

Embed a playlist

1. Sign in to your YouTube account on a computer.
2. On the left side of the page, click Playlists.
3. For the playlist you want to embed, click its title.
4. Click Share .
5. Click Embed.
6. From the box that appears, copy the HTML code.
7. Paste the code into your blog or website HTML.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en

Comment: That's custom, you are going to need some HTML / Javascript for that.  Are you familiar with these programing languages?

Comment: Yes I am. Thing is i found the same 'widget' on two different pages and thought it might be sm from youtube or a library/plugin.

Comment: I have built something similar in the past, all custom.  I am not familiar with any plugins or widgets that do this.  But if you want to go the custom route I can point you in the right direction.  Its really pretty straight forward.

Comment: Custom it is then.

Comment: So basically code out your layout static.  A list of videos on the right in a "drawer" and then a large youtube video on the left.  Instead of passing href youtube links pass the url via javascript and change the source of the video with javascript.